# NoSuchMethodError exception during indexing the pdf files in solr using tika

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am trying to index the pdf files in solr but I am getting NoSuchMethodError in AutoDetectParser in Tika. I am using tika-parser-1.0.jar and tika-core-1.0.jar and solrCell-3.6.0 jar.

*data-Config.xml:*

```
<dataConfig>
     <dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
     <document>
         <entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
             processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
             baseDir="C:\Users\Seetha\Desktop\pdfFiles"
             fileName=".*pdf"
             onError="skip"
             recursive="true">
             <field name="doc" column="doc" />
             <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
             <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
             <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />
             <field column="file" name="fileName"/>

         <entity name="tika-test" dataSource="bin" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                      url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onError="skip">
             <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
             <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
             <field column="text" name="content"/>
           </entity>
         </entity>
     </document>
</dataConfig>
```

*Schema.xml:*

```
<field name="doc"   type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  omitTf="true"     required="true"  /> 
   <field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="size" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="lastmodified" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="fileName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="content" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```

Please let me know what is the solution for this.
Is this due to jar versions mismatch? If anybody posts a link to properly configure the
solr to index pdf files then it would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tika 1.0 looks a little old. I'd suggest you either check what Tika version your SolrCell jar defines itself as requiring, or try upgrading Tika + SolrCell

Comment: Hey Gagravarr, Thanks for the reply. I used Tika 1.4 and Solr 4.6 and its working fine :-) May be it was because of the jars mismatch.